# how do I debug a c program using visual studio code on macOS?

Tags: c, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have installed apple developer tools, gcc and Xcode

on debugging it takes me to settings.json where the c row is highlighted

Comment: Did you follow all the official instructions? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

Comment: yes i tried but i get the message  command not found: code.   on terminal

Comment: Then you haven't added VSCode to your command line paths: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line

Comment: i did it and now code .  works but I'm still not able to debug

Comment: take a look at this https://dev.to/jerrygoyal/run-debug-get-intellisense-for-c-c-in-vscode-4e0o